# How can you make sure that exactly n project is running in bash?

Tags: bash, asynchronous, synchronization, synchronous

I have a program that processes files in a really disk-usage heavy way. I want to call this process on many fies, and experience shows that the performance is the best, when there are no more than 3 process started at the same time (otherwise they are competing for the disk-usage as resource too much and slow each other down). Is there an easy way to call commands from a list and start executing the new one when there are less than n (3) of the processes (started by the listed commands) are running at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xargs`. From [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
--max-procs=max-procs
-P max-procs
      Run  up  to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If
      max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible  at
      a  time.   Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances are that
      only one exec will be done.
```

For example, assuming your commands are one per line:

```
printf 'sleep %dm\n' 1 2 3 4 5 6 | xargs -L1 -P3 -I {} sh -c {}
```

Then, in a terminal:

```
$ pgrep sleep -fa
11987 sleep 1m
11988 sleep 2m
11989 sleep 3m
$ # a little while later
$ pgrep sleep -fa  
11988 sleep 2m
11989 sleep 3m
12045 sleep 4m
```

The `-L1` option uses one line at a time as the argument, and `-I {}` indicates that `{}` will be replaced with that line. To actually run the command, we pass it to `sh` as an argument to `-c`.